# Why I get org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of when I changed my query?

Tags: php, android, json

I have my php file starting with

```
if (isset($_POST['uzip']))
{
$uzip = $_POST['uzip'];
```

With Below I dont get a response

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CAT_ID, CAT_NAME, B_ID, B_NAME, B_EMAIL, B_ADDR, B_ZIP FROM Business INNER JOIN Categories ON Business.BCAT_ID = Categories.CAT_ID , Users WHERE Users.U_ZIP = Business.B_ZIP AND User.U_ZIP='".$uzip."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Below returns a response

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CAT_ID, CAT_NAME, B_ID, B_NAME, B_EMAIL, B_ADDR, B_ZIP FROM Categories INNER JOIN Business ON BCAT_ID = CAT_ID") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I resolve this? is it the post parameter inside the WHERE clause?

Comment: Why don't you use `join` on `Users` as well?

Comment: I have, the following gets a results but why? $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Categories.CAT_NAME, Categories.CAT_ID, Business.B_ID, Business.B_NAME, Business.B_EMAIL, Business.B_ADDR, Business.B_ZIP FROM Business INNER JOIN Categories ON Business.BCAT_ID = Categories.CAT_ID , Users WHERE Business.B_ZIP = Users.U_ZIP AND Users.U_ZIP = '$uzip' GROUP BY Business.B_NAME"

Comment: First, you problem is that in the where clause you have `AND User.U_ZIP='".$uzip."'"`. Your table name is `Users` but here you have typed `User`. This causes error. But, What I do not get is that why are you joining `Users` table? You are not using it anyway in this query!